# Is there an array[index1,index2] data structure in Netlogo?

Tags: netlogo

Is there an extension to Netlogo that allows the creation of multi-dimensional arrays accessed with an "array[i,j]" style notation? I find that using item leads to long and difficult to read code, and I just get lost with anything over 2D lists (though I realise others are perfectly comfortable with it).

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not that I know of, but it's pretty easy to make a primitive to do this yourself. Here's a couple different implementations to give you ideas:

Using recursion:

```
to-report nested-get [ lst indices ]
  ifelse empty? indices [
    report lst
  ] [
    report nested-get (item first indices) (but-first indices)
  ]
end
```

Using [reduce](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#reduce):

```
to-report nested-get [ lst indices ]
  report reduce [ [ l i ] -> item i l ] fput lst indices
end
```

I chose to put the indices after the list in the arguments to better match the syntax you were hoping for, but you might consider putting them before, to correspond with `item`. The reporters are invoked as follows:

```
observer> show nested-get [ [ "a" "b" "c" ] [ "d" "e" "f" ] ]  [1 2]
observer: "f"
```

Unfortunately, if you want to use variables or reporters as your indices, you'll need to use `list` instead of `[]`:

```
observer> let i 0 let j 1 show nested-get [ [ "a" "b" "c" ] [ "d" "e" "f" ] ]  (list i j)
observer: "b"
```

The syntax supports an arbitrary amount of nesting. You could also make dimension specific versions to make the syntax simpler for common cases:

```
to-report item2 [ i j lst ]
  report item j item i lst
end
```

Comment: How could nested-get be used with replace-item to change the value of nested-get my_array (list i j)?

Comment: You would need to create a corresponding `nested-replace-item`. However, there's probably a better way to do what you're trying to do. I recommend opening a new StackOverflow question that more fully describes what your overall goal is.

Answer (score 2):

Now there is an  extension to netlogo that called :  array

Here is an example of code :

```
extensions [array ]

to  setup 
set ex array:from-list n-values 10 [0]
set i 1

while [i < 10  ][
   array:set ex i i + 1
]
end
```